# Wrong output with C++ Linked List using vector and struct

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, struct

I'm new to C++, and recently have been into a problem.

I try to create a Linked List by using struct, and store all the reference in a vector, but I don't know why when I recall the value, the values changes.

I'll be more specific. Here's the code:

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
};

int main() {
    vector<int> a = { 2, 4, 3 };
    vector<ListNode> aListNode;

    aListNode.push_back(ListNode(a[0]));
    for (int i = 1; i < a.size(); i++) {
        aListNode.push_back(ListNode(a[i]));
        aListNode[i - 1].next = &aListNode[i];
        cout << aListNode[i - 1].next->val << endl;
    }

    cout << aListNode[0].next->val << endl;

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
4
3
-17891602
```

But the expected result is:

```
4
3
4
```

I think the problem is from using pointers, but I'm still unsure where.

Comment: You are storing pointers to the vector elements, if the vector's storage is reallocated as a result of a `push_back` you will invalidate every single one of those pointers. Why aren't you using a `std::list` anyway?

Comment: @user657267, that should be an answer

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall probably best marked as a dupe as user2079303 has kindly found.

Comment: @user657267 Oh yes, that's the case, thanks for your answer!

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall well, I was wrong for the time. I don't need to use std::list, just change from vector<ListNode> to vector<ListNode*>